# Ubuntu 20.04 Mail Setup Setting the Default From Address

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-email-address

I am setting up my mail server using this chapter of a setup guide https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu.

When doing a simple test to make sure postfix will send the email, using this line --> echo "test email" | sendmail your-account@gmail.com everything works as expected, ie. the defaulted from mail address is root@myserveraddress.com

However when using this test using 'mail' instead of 'sendmail', mail username@gmail.com with mail the defaulted from address is different, it is root@mail.myserveraddress.com.  (I will later change the defaults so the mails are not coming from root).

My confusion is finding the source of the subdomain use in the default from the mail program.  I am not sure where this is coming from exactly, as the sendmail works fine.

ubuntu 20.04
mail version = 3.4.13

Comment: Also check what is in the file `/etc/mailname`

Answer (score 0):

This information *should* be located in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. Open the file and look for two variables:

```
myhostname=server.myserveraddress.com
mydomain=myserveraddress.com
```

**Note:** If you do not have a `mydomain` variable, you can add it.

Restart Postfix and you should be good:

```
sudo systemctl restart postfix.service
```

Comment: `root@mail:~# echo "test 00000999" | sendmail myemailaddress@yahoo.com
    root@mail:~# mail myemailaddress@yahoo.com
    Cc:
    Subject: test lllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
    a test ...............................

    another line
    root@mail:~#`
for some reason it is not working, here are the two tests, the 'mail' test comes back with a different from after adding a mydomain to /etc/postfix/main.cf